# Find all pairs of $(m, n)$ where $m, n \in \mathbb Z$ for which $m/n + n/m$ is an integer.

Tags: number-theory

Find all pairs of $(m, n)$ where $m, n \in \mathbb Z$ for which $m/n + n/m$ is an integer.

---

Clearly one can find $m, n = +1$, or $- 1$. But are there any other solutions. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Any $m=\pm n$ is also a solution.

Comment: $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n}{m}=k \implies (2 m - k n)^2 + (2n)^2= (k n)^2$

Answer (score 2):

### Hint:

For $m = n$ , the condition is always True.

Consider  $ m \ne n $ such that : $$\frac mn =  x \text{ and  } \frac nm = y \space \space $$

Then $$\frac1x +  x = n \space \space \text{ such that } n\in \mathbb Z$$

Can you find the values of $x$ for which $\frac1x + x $ is an integer?

Comment: I got only +1 or - 1. Any solutions besides this?

Comment: Then you have your answers . But don't forget that $ m = +n $ or $m = -n$ is also a solution.

Comment: The third line is wrong, why are $x$ and $y$ integers?

Comment: It is not required that $x,y\in\Bbb Z$, though

Comment: Ok then you are telling that, m, n are either +1 or - 1 and there are no more solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections !

Comment: If you correct it like that, why is $\frac{1}{x}$ an integer in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $d=gcd(m,n)$. Write 
$$m=dm' \\
n=d n'$$

Then, $gcd(m',n')=1$ and 
$$\frac{m'}{n'}+\frac{n'}{m'} \in \mathbb Z$$

Thus 
$$m'n'|(m')^2+(n')^2$$

Deduce from here that $m'| (n')^2$. Since $gcd(m',n')=1$, you'll get that $m'=\pm 1$.

Same way $n'|(m')^2$ will imply that $n'=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the expression does not change when we multiply $n,m$ by the same factor. Hence consider first the case that $\gcd(n,m)=1$. Then
$$\frac nm+\frac mn =\frac{n^2+m^2}{nm}=2+\frac{(n+m)^2}{nm}.$$
As $\gcd(n+m,n)=\gcd(n,m)=1$ and $\gcd(n+m,m)=\gcd(n,m)=1$, the fraction at the end is already in shortest terms, perhaps up to a unit, i.e., we need $|nm|=1$, so $|n|=|m|=1$.

Allowing $\gcd>1$ again, this amounts to $n=\pm n$ and on the other had, the expression is indeed the integer $\pm2$ if $m=\pm n$.